Banner animation css
I want to create a banner animation with css and html, the first image will fade in and fade out to the second image, the second will fade in and fade out to the third, and the third will fade out to the first image:
#animation{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: Banner_change; 
    animation-duration: 15s; */
    img{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        animation-name: Banner_change;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-duration: 15s;
        &:nth-of-type(1){
            z-index: 1;
            animation-delay: 0s;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(2){
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 0;
            animation-delay: 5s;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(3){
            z-index: 3;
            opacity: 0;
            animation-delay: 10s;
        }
        
    }
    
}


@keyframes Banner_change{
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      25% {
        opacity: 1;
        
      }
      92% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
        
      }
}

base on this https://codepen.io/johnbacon/pen/wgYOXW code, but with three images layered on top of each other.
the html block:
<div id="animation">
                
                <img src="img/banner1.jpg" height="350" width="1000">
                <img src="img/banner2.png" height="350" width="1000">
                <img src="img/banner3.jpg" height="350" width="1000">
                
            </div>

I almost got it working with the above code but the cycles is very strange, the first image won't be fully set to opacity 1 and the cycle will sometime be too quick or too slow, instead of a consistent 5 seconds per image(including fade in and fade out times), it might be something with the delay settings but I don't know how to adjust it.

It works fine for me.

@Meet for me the first image doesn't get as much of a look in. The %s in the animation are not correct.

Let's think about what exactly we want to happen.
Suppose we want an image to fade in for 1 second, stay visible for 5 seconds and fade out for one second, with the fading in and out periods corresponding to the fading out and in of the previous and next images respectively.
The overall timing is 15 seconds, so we want the image to be fading in for 1 second which is approx 6.67% of 15 seconds, then to remain at full opacity for 5 seconds which is from 6.67% to 33.33% of 15 seconds and then fade out for another second which is to 40%. It then remains at opacity 0.


<style>
  #animation {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      animation-name: Banner_change;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-duration: 15s;
      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation-delay: 5s;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation-delay: 10s;
      }
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes Banner_change {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    6.67%,
    33.33% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    40%,
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
<div id="animation">

  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/350" height="350" width="1000">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1000/350" height="350" width="1000">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/350" height="350" width="1000">

</div>



Note: I removed some redundant code just to simplify things.

Thank you for the reply, this is the exact effect I wanted!
